# Downloading every scalar summary in Tensorflow/TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I would like to get all the scalar summary data in Tensorflow summary.

TensorBoard web GUI only allows me to download 1,000 records of the summary. Is there any way I can get every single scalar data that I've put in the summary?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the data you can load it up in python, as an alternative to downloading via tensorboard. See [How to export tensor board data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082908/how-to-export-tensor-board-data) how to do this.